# Polynomial equivalent of $\frac{x+1}{x-1}$

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Is there a way to express $\frac{x+1}{x-1}$ as a polynomial? I have tried:$$\frac{x+1}{x-1} = Ax+B$$ $$(Ax+B)\cdot(x-1)=x+1$$
But such a polynomial seems to contradict its own existence.

Is there any way to express this as a polynomial or is it impossible? Is there maybe a different method for it? A polynomial with negative terms? Maybe a taylor polynomial? Can I try substitute $x$ with $x+1$?

I would really appreciate any help with this.

Comment: There is no such polynomial (with finitely many terms). If one existed, substituting in $ x = 1$ would lead to a contradiction. However, if you allow for a power series (polynomial with infinite degree), then yes you can use the taylor polynomial.

Comment: " A polynomial with negative terms?"  If that is acceptable terminology (it isn't to me) then $\frac {x+1}{x-1}=1+\frac 2{x-1}= 1+\frac {2 -\frac 2x + \frac 2x}{x-1} = 1+2x^{-1} + \frac {\frac 2x}{x-1}=1+2x^{-1} + \frac {\frac 2x -\frac 2{x^2}+\frac 2{x^2}}{x-1} = 1 + 2x^{-1} + 2x^{-2} + 2x^{-3} + .......$  Which is a polynomial with an infinite number of negative terms.  In my opinion that's an oxymoron but ... If you are allowed to make up your terms why not.

Comment: Shouldn't downvote.  It's a legitimate question (where the answer is, no, it isn't a polynomial) and the OP thought about things and came up with legitimate observations.  Someone ought to answer why "rational expressions" (which this is) will not be a polynomial.

Comment: "But such a polynomial seems to contradict its own existence" It does indeed!  If $\frac{x+1}{x-1}=\sum_{k=0}^n a_k x^k$ then $x+1= (x-1)(\sum_{k=0}^n a_k x^k)= a_nx^{n+1} + \sum_{k=1}^n (a_k-a_{k-1})x^k - a_0$. But we assume it is an $n$ degree polynomial so $a_n\ne 0$ and $a_nx^{n+1} = x$ so $n=0$ and .... it just won't  work.   So no such finite non-negative degree polynomial can exist. (Also as Calvin Lin pointed out, if it were $P(x) =\sum_{k=0}^n a_k x^k$ then $P(1) = \sum a_k \in \mathbb R$.   But $\frac {1+1}{1-1}$ is undefined.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you allow infinite expression like [Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) and [Laurent series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series) into your definition of polynomial, then you *can* express the function in such a way.

---

Notice that
$$
\frac{x+1}{x-1} = \frac{2 +(x-1)}{x-1} = \frac{2}{x-1} +1 = \boxed{2(x-1)^{-1} +1 }\tag{1}
$$
The above equation corresponds to the Laurent series at $x=1$. You can see it as a polynomial in $x-1$ with a negative exponent. You can also see that the above expression is well defined for all $x \neq 1$.

Recalling the formula of a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Closed-form_formula) we know that $\frac{1}{x-1} = -\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} x^n$ which converges for $|x| <1$. With this in mind, another way to express your function is
$$
\frac{x+1}{x-1} =  1+2\frac{1}{x-1}=1-2\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} x^n =\boxed{ -1-2\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} x^n, \quad \forall |x|<1} \tag{2}
$$
The above equation is the Taylor series centered at $x =0$ of your function.

Lastly, if you want another infinite polynomial that converges when $|x|>1$ we can do the following
$$
\frac{x+1}{x-1} = 1-\frac{2}{x}\frac{1}{\left(\frac{1}{x}-1\right)} =  1+\frac{2}{x}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{x}\right)^n = \boxed{1+2\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} x^{-n},\quad \forall |x|>1} \tag{3}
$$
Since we applied the geometric series formula to $1/x$, by saying that $|1/x| <1$ this then implies that $|x| >1$, obtaining the desired convergence. This last equation corresponds to the Laurent expansion of your function at $x = \infty$, or at $1/x = 0$.